# UTF GET parameter codification problem in JSP (JBoss 2.0.1)

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, jboss, character-encoding

I´m trying to take a string from a GET or POST parameter in JSP with some accents in UTF-8:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String value = request.getParameter("q");
    out.print(value+" | aáa");
%>
```

The codification of the hardcoded string is correct but the codification of the value obtrained from the parameter (example: `http://whatever/utf.jsp?q=a%E9a`) it´s wrong.

I have already modify the the server.xml dropping the URIEnconding UTF-8.
So I don´t now what I have to do to show the data in the correct format. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need `a%c3%a1a` to represent an UTF-8 URL-encoded value of `aáa`.

Also check the outcome of [`java.net.URLEncoder#encode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and this [online URL encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/UrlEncode/Encode.aspx).